# C/C++ Preprocessor for Ruby/Rake on a CoffeeScript (or any string)

Tags: ruby, coffeescript, rake, preprocessor, c-preprocessor

I have a Coffeescript/Javascript project that is a large web application and I'm using the C++ preprocessor to piece the files together with some `#ifdef` and `#include` directives. It has dramatically simplified and organized my source. I'm using [`rake`](http://rake.rubyforge.org/) as my build tool.

I can call the `cpp -E -Xpreprocessor` directive as a system call from rake, but I'd love to be able to just use it within the Rake script itself.

*e.g. current usage*

```
pre_processed_code = `cpp -E -Xpreprocessor -DDebug app.coffee`
```

Are the any ruby implementations of the C++ preprocessor that you can run a string through or can anyone suggest a better pre-processing workaround?

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve?  Producing different JS output from coffeescript via IfDef and Include?

Comment: @Winfield I use `#ifdef` and `#include` paired to have some data for debug and some different logic loaded if I'm testing locally and I will use `#include` by itself to load different prototypes that are stored in individual files.

Comment: @Winfield harnessing macros would be nice too, but I haven't made any plans for that yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails solves problems like this with [the asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html). It can orchestrate the CoffeeScript -> JavaScript transforms, and you can readily include source files (or directory trees) to have them concatenated and minified.

Sprockets supports chaining filters. For example, `foo.js.coffee` will be treated as CoffeeScript that produces JavaScript, which may itself include other dependencies and is a candidate for minification. Pulling in external variables for conditional compilation, inlining objects from a database, and other wacky behavior can be readily accommodated by chaining in other filters, e.g. `foo.js.coffee.erb`:

```
<% if environment == 'production' %>
log = (args...) ->
  # no-op
<% else %>
log = (args...) ->
  console.log(args...)
<% end %>
```

All this is customarily executed on the fly in development and via in a compilation step in production, where individual source files are processed, joined, and optimized before delivery to the web server. This all works for CSS preprocessors and JavaScript template languages, too -- if there's a web-related thing that someone wants to compile, there's likely support for it somewhere.

You're probably not using Rails, but that shouldn't stop you from leveraging all this work: the asset pipeline is actually a standalone gem called [Sprockets](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets). You can likely bolt it on in place of your existing build process. This isn't a C++ preprocessor, but it is what a lot of other people are doing to solve this problem.

Comment: I've seen Sprockets before, but it didn't jump to mind for this use. We aren't using rails, but you are right about us still being able to leverage it. Upvote for the moment, and after I play around for a bit I'll accept if it is the best solution. Thanks for the detailed answer!